# how to convert date in UTC format using moment?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

using date picker I am getting this value **"Fri Jan 12 1900 05:21:10 GMT+0521 (India Standard Time)"** I want to get it's value in UTC or UTC in milliseconds or long value.
here is my code

```
 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, moment) {
 $scope.UTC ='';
      $scope.IST = 'Fri Jan 12 1900 05:21:10 GMT+0521 (India Standard Time)';
    });
```

Comment: can you please check my answer and give a feedback? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Moment [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

```
moment.utc(yourDate).format()
```

---

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use moment.utc() instead of moment().
>
> This brings us to an interesting feature of Moment.js. UTC mode.
>
> While in UTC mode, all display methods will display in UTC time instead of local time.